# Reference Request: The Atiyah-Hirzebruch Spectral Sequence

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I have just finished learning the Serre spectral sequence and I would like to learn about the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence. Could someone suggest an accessible reference? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Kochman's *Bordism, Stable Homotopy, and Adams Spectral Sequences* has a brief but detailed section on the AHSS, with emphasis towards applying it to complex-oriented cohomology theories.